# How to get back to my app when PDF comment (in Adobe Reader) is saved in Android

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent, annotations, adobe

It is possible to open a PDF document from my app in Adobe Reader App from Adobe systems.

The user is allowed to add comments (annotations) in the PDF document.The comments in Adobe Reader are saved when the save button is pressed. I want to come back to my app.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can't, yet there is a work around, There are two options

Option 1: 
re-launch your app once the pdf thing is done after storing the values and current (at the time of exit) state of the app. You can use event listener or even a time stamp would do.

or

Option 2:
on saving close the pdf activity or app

As per your question,

1. User makes comments on the pdf
2. User presses the save button
3. changes(comments) are saved.

This is when you need to re launch your app or closing the pdf reader once the changes are saved, from the previous sequence.

Option 2 is much economical.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for help. But how do I know the pdf thing is done? Which values have to be compared? Please describe more detailed your solution. Maybe it can help.

Comment: I can tell you that only when you update me with your sequence of events. Pl update your event seq.

Comment: Do you mean that the timestamp of the file has to be compared?

Comment: Check I've changed it now

Comment: Yes, once the save is successful, You have two options at this point
1. Close the PDF and your app will be as it was befor the pdf was launched
or
2. Re launch your app afresh over the pdf.
the first one is economical.

Answer (score 2):

it can't.

After it's outside your app you have no control over what happens.
Your app will be back in charge only after the user taps the back button back to your app.